# How can i put this two if statements into one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i'm just learning unity and my problem is this code below is working good right now but it seems like can be written shorter can you help me about that?

```
    if (isboosted)
    {
        speed = boostSpeed;
    }
    if (!isboosted)
    {
        speed = normalSpeed;
    }
```

Comment: What does your text-book or tutorial say about **`else`**?

Comment: The commenting system won't let me say simply `else`. You could also use a _ternary_: `speed = isboosted ? boostSpeed : normalSpeed;`

Answer (score 1):

`speed = isboosted ? boostSpeed : normalSpeed;`

Although it's up to you if you find this format more readable.

I'd also suggest

```
if (isBoosted)
{
    speed = boostSpeed;
}
else
{
    speed = normalSpeed;
}
```

is clearer than your original code and possibly easier to follow if you're not used to the ? : syntax.

Comment: What Sean shows you here in the first line is called an inline if. You probably want to avoid using it with bigger conditions as it can be hard to read, but it's perfectly suited for cases like this. The syntax works the following: 

condition ? returned when true : returned when false

Comment: @66Gramms it is actually called [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) ;)

Comment: Oh thank you, that is new for me. I've always just heard it refered to as an inline if. I've learnt something today :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for helps it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **else** statement. The block of an **If** will run if it's condition evaluates to **true**. An **else** block connected to an **if** only runs when the **if**'s condition was **false**, resulting in that block of code not executing.

Your code would look like this:

```
if (isboosted)
{
    speed = boostSpeed;
}
else
{
    speed = normalSpeed;
}
```

Important thing to note, you can only use **else** statements after either an **if** or **else if**

Answer (score 0):

//assuming isboosted is a boolean type

```
if (isboosted)
    speed = boostSpeed;
else
    speed = normalSpeed;
```

//or if you like the braces, they are only needed if your if statement actions have more then one line of code

```
if (isboosted)
{
    speed = boostSpeed;
}
else
{
    speed = normalSpeed;
}
```